# Wordpress: List custom taxonomy with children

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a list of links for a custom taxonomy along with the children of the terms. i.e:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/telephony">Telephony</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/blackberry">BlackBerry</a></li>
            <li><a href="/fixed-ip">Fixed IP</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/email">Email</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/fax">Fax</a></li>
            <li><a href="/text">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="/nhs-email">NHS Email</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So far I've got:

```
    <?php
    $termID = 451;
    $taxonomyName = "service_line_category";
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $termID, $taxonomyName );

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

However this only grabs the children of '$termID = 451;' but I'm not sure how to modify this to get the parents and the children for all of the terms within 'service_line_category' in a list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Alexcp so something like this:

```
    <?php
    $taxonomyName = "service_line_category";
    $termID = get_cat_ID($taxonomyName);
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $termID, $taxonomyName );

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

Obviously this doesn't work but is this along the right lines?

Comment: why post an answer that doesn't work and accept it? Accept cyrils answer if that is what works.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the piece of code you need :

```
<?php
$taxonomyName = "service_line_category";
$terms = get_terms($taxonomyName,array('parent' => 0));
foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug,$taxonomyName).'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
    $term_children = get_term_children($term->term_id,$taxonomyName);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($term_children as $term_child_id) {
        $term_child = get_term_by('id',$term_child_id,$taxonomyName);
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term_child->term_id, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term_child->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable, you can do something like this:

```
$taxonomyName = "service_line_category";
$termID = get_cat_ID($taxonomyName);
```